# how do I get to the desktop after installing ubuntu server in vmware workstation?

Tags: server

I am new to this, very new! Trying to learn! I installed the software, logged in with my username and password, but come to username@ubuntu:~$_

Not sure what this is asking for or what I need to do next. Please help.

Comment: You just logged in, that's the command prompt. If you type some command, for example `echo "Hello World"` it will give you back Hello World.

Answer (score 0):

The server version does not come with a GUI interface configured, if you want a DE, try Xfce (which is lightweight). For this run

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4 lightdm firefox
```

After the installation is complete run `startx`.

---

**Remarks:** If you wanted just the a normal "beginner" installation of Ubuntu, you should have downloaded the Desktop version of the installer. Now,
if you want Gnome3+Unity (the default) run

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

If you want Gnome3+Gnome Shell run

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell gdm firefox nautilus
```

You only need to run one of this lines, and after the installation run `startx`.